# Apply texture in a quad mesh from a texture atlas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, texture-mapping

I'm trying to apply dynamically a texture from a texture atlas to a quad mesh in Unity3D.

When I do the same in a mesh of a cube, the front face works very fine but the other ones get distorted. So I had the idea to use a simple quad and now I'm facing this scenario:

[image]

The image should be displayed like this:

[image]

I'm placing the texture by the code below. The math is working fine:

```
public int offsetX = 0;
public int offsetY = 0;

private const float offset = 0.0625f; // the rate of each texture square

void Start ()
{
    Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;

    Vector2[] UVs = new Vector2[mesh.vertices.Length];

    UVs[0] = new Vector2(offsetX * offset, offsetY * offset);
    UVs[1] = new Vector2((offsetX * offset) + offset, offsetY * offset);
    UVs[2] = new Vector2(offsetX * offset, (offsetY * offset) + offset);
    UVs[3] = new Vector2((offsetX * offset) + offset, (offsetY * offset) + offset);

    mesh.uv = UVs;
}
```

What should I do to place the texture in the quad mesh as the image reference?

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/750572/how-to-render-a-sprite-to-a-quad.html try it out

Comment: @caxapexac I'm doing basically the same but the sprite application I'm doing by the visual interface... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for an answer:

I've fixed that changing the tail (offset) and scale of the shader. Example:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Cube : MonoBehaviour {

    public int offsetX = 0;
    public int offsetY = 0;

    private Renderer _rend;
    private Material _material;

    private const float Offset = 0.0625f;

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start ()
    {
        _rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();

        _material = _rend.material;

        _material.mainTextureScale = new Vector2(Offset,Offset);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        _material.mainTextureOffset = new Vector2(offsetX*Offset,offsetY*Offset);
    }
}
```